# how 2 rows data concat into 1 column of a single row in mysql

Tags: mysql, rows, concatenation

In my Table **sales_order_address** there is 2 rows on each order, 1 record for billing to information and 2 is shipping to information. 
But I want to get billing and shipping address in column and single row.

You can see in screenshot **Veronica6146 Honey Bluff ParkwayCaldershipping Veronica6146 Honey Bluff ParkwayCalderbilling** in 2 rows how can I get into 1 column of a single row?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group_concat()`

```
select order_id,group_concat(concat(first_name, street,city,address_type))
from tablename
group by order_id
```

Comment: Fahmi ? 

you query return only 1 row Even i need 14 rows .
you can see in screenshot there is 28 recorde 1 for billing and 2 for shipping .

Comment: i want to combine billing and shipping record in 1 row of each order , not all orders

Comment: @HaFizUmer, could u please add your expected output in your question

Comment: @Fehmi Thank you its working just add group by clause 


select parent_id, group_concat(concat(firstname, street,city,address_type)) 
from sales_order_address

GROUP BY parent_id;


Please Edit your answer

Comment: @HaFizUmer, I've also edited my answer - added a group by clause with order_id